# Java - Cannot find symbol Set/Get

Tags: java

I am new to Java.

I am working on a small project to familiarize myself a little more Java. I am using examples out of the book and I am doing fine except for these cannot find symbol errors. I know there is an issue with my constructor, or rather how I am calling it.

I am getting an error for the name, age, battles, health etc...

I just posted a few examples of the code so I don't clutter this with the same thing.

EDIT: SOLVED! Thanks every body for your help.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `Kight myKnight = new Knight()` before you try to reference it.

```
Knight myKnight = new Knight();


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Welcome young knight.\n" );

String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "What is your name? \n" );
myKnight.setKnightName( name );
String welcomeMessage = String.format( "Welcome, %s, to Kiev!", myKnight.getKnightName() );
...
```

---

I didnt realize there were so many errors in here, i assumed there was just 1 error that you mentioned but looking at your code further revels many other errors. Tip: stop writing more code until you fix compile time errors and compile frequently expeically at your level. Your only making things harder for yourself by continuing to write more code while these compiler errors exist, you need to pause what your doing and go back and fix errors 1 at a time. You seem to have a problem where you are trying to use variables that dont exist, your code is riddled with them: `this.knightName = name;` *what is `name` and where does it exist? (it doesnt)*.

I remember when I first started programming many years ago I would goof around and see how long I could go without compiling and get 0 compile time errors *it wasn't long*.

Comment: He also needs to fix the constructor or Knight won't compile

Comment: I tried Knight myKnight = new Knight(); previously and I still received the same errors. What is wrong with my constructor?

Comment: You are referencing name, and other instance variables, but not passing them.  Pass all the instance variables.  Like `public Knight(String name, double health ...)`

Comment: @user2419571 your trying to use variables that dont exist.

Comment: "What's wrong with your constructor" is that it's at the bottom of your code, probably?  You're trying to tell the program to construct a new object after you've already tried to use the (not-yet-created) object for a bunch of stuff.  Kind of like trying to drive a car before it's been manufactured.

Comment: You have to pick either a setter for each step or a constructor to construct all at once.  Just delete that new Knight line and remove the constructor.  Create a new Knight first then use the default constructor `new Knight()` and continue calling the setters

Comment: Ok, that all makes sense now. Thanks every body for the help. Honestly, I was working on this so late last night that I was only further confusing myself. I woke-up and looked at and what do you know, I understood everything that is going on again.